# How to export Atlassian Confluence wide table in pdf without clipping columns?

Tags: confluence, export-to-pdf

I have wide table in a confluence page and I would like to export it to PDF. When I do that, the resulting document has the table clipped on the right and columns that do not fit the width are missing.

Is there a way to format the table so it can be entirely exported to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but Confluence has two types of tables: Responsive (default) and Fixed Width.

When you export to PDF, and the tables are set to Responsive, you should see a landscape-oriented PDF with equally spaced columns (mileage may vary), but it will fill the width of the page.

If you set the table to Fixed Width (click a table cell, go to the table toolbar at the top of the editor and click **Responsive** on the left, which will activate a drop-down. Select **Fixed Width**.

Now, this will set the width of the table to the currently displayed width, but you should be able to hover over the table cell vertical crossbars and you will see that you have the option to move the cell widths left and right.

This is Confluence 6.6.1. On the day of your writing, Confluence released 6.1.4.

Check out the [release notes for Confluence 6.1.4 here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/issues-resolved-in-6-1-4-907280990.html)